# Choppy movement

Tags: xna, movement, timer

So, I'm trying to write some code in C# XNA to make an enemy move in a random direction for 0.5 seconds, then switch direction and once again move for 0.5 seconds. However the problem I've discovered is that the way I've done it, the movement becomes choppy, as in the instead of smoothly transitioning from Y1 to Y2 the enemy just "jumps" over there. The code for the movement is:

```
public static void enemy_movement()
    {
        int direction;
        for (int i = 0; i < enemy1_pos.Count; i++)
        {
            direction = rand.Next(4); //The enemy's movement direction
            Vector2 v = enemy1_pos[i];

                if (direction == 0) //Down
                {
                    v.Y += enemy1_speed;
                }
                else if (direction == 1) //Up
                {
                    v.Y -= enemy1_speed;
                }
                else if (direction == 2) //Right
                {
                    v.X += enemy1_speed;
                }
                else //Left
                {
                    v.X -= enemy1_speed;
                }
                enemy1_pos[i] = v;
            }
}
```

and this is the code calling on the function

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime) {
        enemy1_time += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
        if (enemy1_time > 500)
        {
            enemy1_time -= 500;
            Action.enemy_movement();
        }
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: random direction means any direction ? or just up, down, left, right ? im confused

Comment: Up, down, left and right. The integer 'direction' is set to a random number between 0 and 3. It then checks what number 'direction' is and sends, or in this case makes the enemy jump, towards a certain direction.

Comment: Well, the reason that it is "choppy" is because you are just moving it every 500ms

Comment: How can I change it to move it the same distance during the same time, but smoother?

Comment: "distance/time=velocity" you just add "velocity*gametime" to your position every frame(if 1 second equals the value 1 in gameTime). if you want to move in a different direction every 500ms, just change the velocity after 500ms. => you want it to move 2 units in 1 second => 2/1=2 => move with 2*gameTime in your desired direction every tick.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than move your enemy every 500ms you should define how far an enemy should move in 1 second. For example, say an enemy can move 3 distance units every second. If you know the time between the last frame in milliseconds you can simply do this:

(pseudo code)

```
enemy_units_per_second = 3.0;
delta_time_ms = get_elapsed_time_ms();
enemy_movement_distance = enemy_units_per_second * (delta_time_ms / 1000.0);
```

This will allow your enemy to move in smooth increments every frame. The enemy will also move the same distance at the same speed, regardless of frame-rate.

Answer (score 0):

As Shiro mentioned in the comments, you only move the enemy every half second. Instead you've got to set the direction every half second rather than moving it in a random direction, and make sure it always moves in the direction. And please use a switch rather than such a chain of if else's :)